# How to add dots indicators on Wear application

Tags: android, android-layout, wear-os, android-viewpager2, wearables

I have a simple ViewPager2 on my activity.
Like this one :

```
<androidx.viewpager2.widget.ViewPager2
    android:id="@+id/balanceProfilPager"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    />
```

I need to add dots Indicator on the top of screen, but I don't find sample.
I don't know how can I do that.
[Sample of my need](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ud8if.png)
Thank you very much for your help

Answer (score 0):

use this library for this integration:

```
https://github.com/smarteist/Android-Image-Slider
```

if you want to create custom bubble then change the colour in viewPager page listerner

Comment: Thank you very much.
Is it possible, with this library, to have dots curbed on the wear Round and dots flat on the wear Square ?